# Writing to txt in a loop using Fortran 90

Tags: text, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I have a this subroutine to write some data into a txt file. The problem is that the code writes all the data in a single line. This is my code.

```
  SUBROUTINE writetht(Nd, outpath , Tht , Dz , Ct)
        INTEGER :: Nd , i, Ct
        REAL :: Dz , Z
        REAL, DIMENSION(Nd) :: Tht
        CHARACTER(54) :: outpath
        CHARACTER(12) :: filename
        write(filename,'("Tht_",I3,".TXT")')Ct
        OPEN (003, FILE = outpath // filename)
        DO i = 1 , Nd
            Z = Dz * (i - 1)
            WRITE(003, '(2F7.3, 1X)') Z , Tht(i)
        END DO
        CLOSE(003)
    END SUBROUTINE writetht
```

The output looks like this in the txt file:

```
  0.000  0.484  5.000  0.321 10.000  0.321 15.000  0.321 20.000  0.321 25.000  0.321 30.000  0.321 35.000  0.321 40.000
```

But I want to have it as:

```
0.000   0.484  
5.000   0.321 
10.000  0.321 
15.000  0.321 
20.000  0.321
```

I am using gfortran compiler for Fortran90.

Comment: possible line-ending type issue. eg your file has linux line ends for some reason and you open in a windows editor.   Why do you want a space at the end of the line, by the way?

Comment: I think you are right. I changed the file format to xls and it came out perfect. Thanks.

Comment: good. note changing the extension doesn't do anything to the file from the fortran side, it just causes a different app to open it.

Comment: Also get into the habit of always using Implicit None